# How can I replace part of a slice with another in go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I would like to see if there is a simple way to replace a portion of a slice with all the values of another slice. For instance:

```
x := []int{1,2,0,0}
y := []int{3,4}

// goal is x == {1,2,3,4}

x[2:] = y    // compile error
x[2:] = y[:] // compile error
```

I know that I can always iterate through through y, but Go has a bunch of cool features and I'm pretty new to Go. So perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices, https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices, https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the builtin [copy](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy):

> The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a destination slice.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2, 0, 0}
    y := []int{3, 4}

    copy(x[2:], y)

    fmt.Println(x) // [1 2 3 4]
}
```

- https://play.golang.org/p/TL6Bv4OGeqE

Stealing from the above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623191/how-can-i-replace-part-of-a-slice-with-another-in-go/60623228#comment107253251_60623191), you can learn more on slices here:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices
- https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices
- https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

I also found this blog post informative: https://divan.dev/posts/avoid_gotchas/#arrays-and-slices

Comment: Thanks miku! That worked perfectly. Also, the play.golang.org link was really cool.

Answer (score 1):

There is one [`Replace`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Replace) function in `x/exp/slices`:

> Replace replaces the elements s[i:j] by the given v, and returns the modified slice. Replace panics if s[i:j] is not a valid slice of s.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/exp/slices"
)

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2, 0, 0}
    y := []int{3, 4}
    z := slices.Replace(x, 2, 4, y...)
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IyIzQ3iS5aF)

Comment: watch out that currently `Replace` has a bug by which it doesn't panic on invalid `i` and `j` values, but instead returns a corrupted slice. [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56700).

Comment: Wow, @blackgreen, thank you very much for your information. This issue is resolved for now.